# pynqのアップデートが出来ません。

Tags: python, pip, fpga

FPGAボードのPYNQ-Z1の初期設定をしているのですが、うまく出来ません。

```
xilinx@pynq:~$ sudo /home/xilinx/scripts/update_pynq.sh
```

のように実行すれば、いいとweb上には書いてあるのですが、
`scripts`のフォルダーが存在しない為、アップデートが出来ません。
アップデートが出来ない為か、`pip`を使うこともできません。
どうすれば良いのでしょうか？

追記
[公式のセットアップ](https://pynq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/pynq_z1_setup.html)を見てセットアップをしましたが、`pip`が使えなかったため、
[FPGAでDeep Learningしてみる](https://qiita.com/ykshr/items/6c8cff881a200a781dc3)の

```
xilinx@pynq:~$ sudo /home/xilinx/scripts/update_pynq.sh
```

の箇所を実行しましたが、ファイルが存在しなかったため、実行することが出来ません。
正直な所、`pip`さえ使えれば、アップデートをできなくてもいいのですが、`pip`が使えないので、アップデートをしたら治るのかなと…

Comment: 「実行すればいい」と書いてある(あなたが参照した)ページの URL を質問に含めて下さい。あるはずのファイルが見つからないなら、前の手順から見直す必要があるかもしれません。 / また、ファイル名で検索すると同じような問題が発生したという記事がいくつか出てきます。

Comment: その記述はこの記事でしょうか。[FPGAでDeep Learningしてみる](https://qiita.com/ykshr/items/6c8cff881a200a781dc3) 日付や記述からすると古い[Version 1.4](https://pynq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html#version-1-4)のようです。前回の質問[pynqでのファイル指定のエラーです。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/73685/26370)の参照先に書かれていたこちらの手順[PYNQ-Z1 Setup Guide](https://pynq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/pynq_z1_setup.html)とか参照先記事中の[pynq のセットアップ](https://qiita.com/nishimuraatsushi/items/3e5f161eca4b2a0f06c8#pynq-%E3%81%AE%E3%82%BB%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%82%A2%E3%83%83%E3%83%97)に沿ってセットアップ出来ていれば不要なのでは？

Comment: おそらく「FPGAでDeep Learningしてみる」を参考に何かするのは間違いでしょう。また前回質問参照先の「PYNQ で遊ぶ : 1. LED を点滅させる」やさらにその参照先の「PYNQ-Z1 Setup Guide」「PYNQ を使って Python で手軽に FPGA を活用 (2)」の何処にも`pip`を使う処理は書かれていないようですが、何故`pip`を使おうとしたのでしょうか？ `pip`は`python`のモジュールで`PYNQ`とは独立しており、`PYNQ`をアップデートしたとしても`pip`のアップデートとは関連はありません。`pip`はそれ自身を単体で`python`にインストールするかアップデートするべきものです。

Comment: python自体は、元から入っています。しかし、`pip`が使えない。どこに書いてあるかは忘れましたが、`pip`は初期では使えないと書いてあるサイトがあったので、`pip`が使えないこと自体は以上ではないようです。

Comment: OSは何でしょう。例えば Ubuntuとかなら `apt`で別パッケージ入れたりする必要があります。あと `python -m pip 〜` で使えることもあります

Comment: いまいち議論が噛み合っていないようです。「本当は何をしたいのか」が重要なのであって、「pynqのアップデート」や「pipを使いたい」というのは的外れな目的や手段の取り違えと思われます。結局は「FPGAボードのPYNQ-Z1の初期設定をしているのですが、うまく出来ません。」という状況の原因を探って解決することが本来の質問とするべきことなのではないでしょうか？

Comment: ボード使うための `pynq` ノートブックを, `pip` で取り込みたいけど(コマンド無いから)取り込めないという話では？ (スタート位置にも立ってないという話)

Answer (score 0):

PYNQ-Z1 のことは正直分かりませんが
とりあえず最新版のソフトがあれば動くかもしれないのなら, その手順記しときます

[PYNQ Introduction](https://pynq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

- [PYNQ-Z1 Setup Guide](https://pynq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/pynq_z1_setup.html)

上記リンクによれば「すべてのサンプルノートブック」は GitHub にあるようです
https://github.com/xilinx/pynq

> Python Source Code
> All Python code for the pynq package can be found in the /pynq folder. This folder can be found on the board after the board boots with the precompiled image.
> To update your PYNQ SD card to the latest pynq package, you can run the following command from a terminal connected to your board:
>
> > sudo pip3 install --upgrade --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed pynq

どの Linuxディストリビューションか不明ですが (Linuxかどうかも不明)
`pip`/`pip3` コマンドが最初は入ってないこともあります。

その場合 `python3 -m pip` に置き換えて使うことができるかもしれません (このように)

```sh
sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed pynq
```

ただ, (Linuxディストリビューションで)使えないようになってるのはシステム側環境を破壊されないように, というのもあるので, `venv` などの仮想環境を整えて, そちらで行うのがよいかもしれない